# Unity3d game does not receive push notifications

Tags: c#, java, android, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I am building a game using Unity3d, that is going to use the GCM service (which I wrote into a custom library). But here is my problem. This custom library works, as long as it is in a native android application.

The moment I put it in the Unity3d game and send a push notification, the device does not receive the push notification. I know the library is accessable, because I can read the debug logs in the logcat, that are from the library.

I think Unity3d somehow prevents the GCM service from running, thus preventing the device from receiving push notifications.

Is there anything I should know about Unity3d, that causes this problem? Or did someone had a similiar problem? Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: You might need to create an AndroidManifest.xml that enables GCM and put that into Assets/Plugins/Android. This replaces the Unity generated manifest in the .apk file.

Comment: I tried something like that, except that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As far I know Unity doesn't have conflicts with GCM service.

If it helps, here is a link to use GCM on Unity through a plugin.

https://github.com/kobakei/unity-gcm